# How can I count the item in a list like this

Tags: python, list

There are 3 items, 'Peter', 'Tom, 'Vincent'

if I want to input 5 times to check how many times my inputs match the required items, what should I use?

I tried `.count` method but it did not match my requirement...

For example,

my inputs:

```
Tom

David

David

Vincent

Sam
```

Expected output should be: `Number = 2`

Should I use `list` or `dict` or other methods?

Comment: you mean to say, you have a source list, and you need to find how many occurs from the source list, from the inputs you enter?. please post what code you have tried so far.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Why is the answer `2`?

Comment: list intersection? Is that what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a loop that increments a counter.

```
count = 0
items = ['Peter', 'Tom', 'Vincent']
inputs = ['Tom', 'David', 'David', 'Vincent', 'Sam']
for el in inputs:
    if el in items:
        count += 1
print("Number =", count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a list intersection of your inputs with required items

```
seek = ['Peter', 'Tom', 'Vincent']
my_inputs = ['Tom', 'David', 'David', 'Vincent', 'Sam']

len([x for x in my_inputs if x in seek]) // 2
```

So basically for each of your input, you wanna see if it matches any item in seek. Simply build such a list of intersection, and do `len` on it

your inputs may repeat:

```
seek = ['Peter', 'Tom', 'Vincent']
my_inputs = ['Tom', 'Tom', 'David', 'David', 'Vincent', 'Sam', 'Peter']

len([x for x in my_inputs if x in seek]) // 4
```

***EDIT***: although it shows how powerful list comprehensions in python are, but requires extra-space (O(N) where N is len(my_inputs)) whereas Barmar's solution requires O(1) extra-space, so you'd probably be better off with Barmar's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hello dear @tse chun hei!

An elegant and effient way of doing it is through numpy:

```
inputs = ['Tom','David','David','Vincent','Sam']
items = ['Peter','Tom','Vincent']
```

You can then combine `np.isin()` with `np.sum()` and get your output with one line of code:

```
np.sum(np.isin(inputs,items))
2
```

I hope this post was usefull!

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `Counter` in the `collections` module for this:

```
from collections import Counter
all_items = Counter(['Tom', 'David', 'David', 'Vincent', 'Sam'])
```

`Counter` is a subclass of `dict`. The `all_items` counter will look like this:

```
Counter({'Tom': 1, 'David': 2, 'Vincent': 1, 'Sam': 1})
```

You could then get the count of a key that you pass like this:

```
all_items.get('Tom') 

Output: 1

all_items.get('David')

Output: 2
```

To get multiple items, you could do the following:

```
items_to_check = ['Peter', 'Tom', 'Vincent'] # your list of multiple items to check

for item in items_to_check:
    print(f"Item: {item} \t Count: {all_items.get(item)}")
```

Output:

```
Item: Peter      Count: None
Item: Tom        Count: 1
Item: Vincent    Count: 1
```

To get the sum:

```
sum([x[1] for x in all_items.items() if x[0] in items_to_check])

Output: 2
```